# Transform long format dataframe with multiples sets of columns into wide format

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table, tidyr

How can you transform a long format dataframe with multiple sets of columns into a wide format?

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2),
  uid = c("m1", "m2"),
  germ = c(23, 24),
  category = c("x1", "x2"),
  mineral = c(78, 10))
```

Names come from `uid` and `category` while Values come from `germ` and `mineral`. I have tried working on this with the code below but the names are not what I want

```
out_df <- df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = c(uid, category), values_from = c(germ, mineral))
```

Here is what I would like my output to look like

```
out_df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2),
                     m1 = c(23, NA),
                     m2 = c(NA, 24),
                     x1 = c(78, NA),
                     x2 = c(NA, 10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to get the expected output is to apply `pivot_wider` twice:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "uid", values_from = "germ") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "category", values_from = "mineral")

# A tibble: 2 x 5
#     id    m1    m2    x1    x2
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    23    NA    78    NA
#2     2    NA    24    NA    10
```